# "service discovery failed" when trying to connect via bluetooth with android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-service-discovery

I want to get the android sample project "BluetoothChat" running on my smartphone HTC One X. When trying to connect to a bluetooth adapter which is connected to my pc I get a "service discovery failed" - error. 
I have already read about solutions that worked for some developers but not for me:

1. I use the standard UUID `00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`
2. I tried to replace 
   `tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);`

with

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
         tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

3. I called `btAdapter.cancelDiscovery()` before connecting

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Does the bluetoothchat application exists on your machine?

The flow is like this for your use case:

1. connect using Rfcomm[serviceID] [services should exist in the bluetooth service discovery databases present in both bluetooth devices]
2. After a wireless connection, the remote RFCOMM service running in another bluetooth device, will search whether the service exists in its service discovery database.If not it will return service not found.

To put it in a one-liner
  The RFCOMM SERVICE requested by one bluetooth device, should be available in the remote device.

feel free to discuss more about it if you are interested..Happy to Help

Comment: As I found out my bluetooth usb-adapter uses another uuid (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb). I tried to run the project using this uuid. Now I get the following error:

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.android.BluetoothChat/com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I tried another example with that new UUID where I get the error "Not able to register SDP record for BASE_UUID"

Comment: what I am trying to communicate is that , the UUID should be the same on both the bluetooth devices. For ex: run the bluetooth chat app on both the bluetooth device.

Comment: android is not running on the other device, it is windows 7; but I took the uuid I wrote above on the android device. And it seems as if it was correct as there is a different error.

Comment: that gives a clue. Obviously windows will not support bluetooth chart.Try using the following UUID for object push https://bluetooth.org/Technical/AssignedNumbers/service_discovery.htm

Comment: I tried without any success. I have also tested the whole thing with Linux running on my pc.